# Trouble With Rvest and html_form_set

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to scrape data from a site using rvest and I'm having some trouble.  Specifically, I'm trying to enter a username and password into a form in an automated way, so I can then use an rvest session to submit queries and grab pieces of the results.  I start with this:

```
sess <- session(<siteURL>)
form <- html_form(sess)
```

and I get this when I take a look at my form object:

```
<some fields I dont care about>
<field> (email) hello$world: 
<field> (password) foo$bar: 
<more fields I dont care about>
```

Yes, of course I'm changing the field names here, but suffice to say it's obvious that hello$world is looking for the user name and foo$bar is looking for the password, and both really do have dollar signs in the field name.

Ok, looks good.  Now all I need to do is set the two form fields I need to enter credentials:

```
formSet <- form %>% html_form_set(
     hello$world = 'abc',
     foo$bar = 'xyz')
```

But this generates this error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "formSet <- form %>% html_form_set(hello$world ="
```

I'd think this was some stupid typo error, but for the life of me I don't see it.
So I'm guessing it has something to do with the dollar sign in the form field names I need to use?  If yes, is there a way to escape this?  But it's not really in a string, so would that even work?  I'm new to this, as you can probably tell.  Thanks for any help.

FYI, my scraping here is minimal stuff. I won't be banging on the site with zillions of requests.  Just a simple, low-data-volume, one-time thing.  Thanks.

Comment: perhaps using `hello$world` , ie. surrounded by backtics, rather than hello$world, defangs the `$` that would tell the compiler that it is looking for a data.frame named hello...unless 'hello' is a df.

Comment: Thanks, @Chris.  Good idea (of course, I've also tried escaping the dollar sign in hello$world with a backslash but no luck).  When I use the backtics, though, I get a different error: "Error in `check_form()`:
! `form` must be a single form produced by html_form()".   Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you have to make a `html_form(` first, then populate it, but I'll have to rtm again on that.